# Working with arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am stuck on a arrays in jQuery. I am returning back from php an array In php file I am adding array like this in a loop:

```
$table_data[]= array("id"=>mysql_result($query,$i,"id"),"name"=>trim(mysql_result($query,$i,"name")));
```

at the end of php file :

```
echo json_encode($table_data);
```

On my jquery :

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "phpfilename.php",
   data: ({
     newtask: "grab"
   }),
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data){
     alert("value - "+data.length);
   }
 });
```

(this returns correct record counts)

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
 alert( "The key is '" + key + "' and the value is '" + value + "'" );
});
```

(the above loop returns me : 
0,1,2  as a key , Object as a value )

I need help with understanidn how to pass arrays from php to jquery and how to handle them . Maybe I am totally on wrong way.

Comment: What's the problem? You're getting the array and looping through it. What are you asking how to do?

Comment: You should read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to learn the basics about arrays and objects in JavaScript. `alert` is the worse debug tool you could have chosen. The output is correct though, since you have an array of objects and the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access any property of an object, the process is:

```
ObjectName.property
```

or

```
ObjectName[''+ property +''];
```

read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {

  // try

  console.log(value.id);
  console.log(value.name);

});
```

Comment: that is it, great. thank you , I was searching it for hours. Thank you very much

Comment: you mean `ObjectName["property"];
`

Comment: $.each(data, function(key, value) {

  // try

  console.log(value.id);
  console.log(value.name);

});  this one was helpfull